# why the table does'nt exist in database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, migration

What's wrong with my code?, the migrating is succes but the table does'nt exist

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('student', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->varchar('student_id', 6)->primary_key()->nullable(false);
        $table->varchar('student_name', 50)->nullable(false);
        $table->enum('student_class', ['RPL-1','RPL-2','RPL-3'])->nullable(true);
        $table->enum('student_gender', ['MALE','FEMALE'])->nullable(true);
        $table->text('student_address')->nullable(true);
        $table->tinyinteger('student_status', ['1'])->default('1');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine; you probably have another problem. Please check if you are viewing the correct database and check if you have reloaded the connection etc.

Comment: I think `string` instead of `varchar`

Comment: show your Student model

Comment: @milo526 i have checked database and the connection but nothing happened

Comment: Also shouldn't it be: `tinyInteger`?

Answer (score 0):

The migration in your example will not run due to trying to use functions that aren't available in Laravel or misuse of the functions.  I've put together a new migration together and tested this and it runs fine.

```
Schema::create('student', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('student_id', 6)->primary_key()->nullable(false);
    $table->string('student_name', 50)->nullable(false);
    $table->enum('student_class', ['RPL-1', 'RPL-2', 'RPL-3'])->nullable(true);
    $table->enum('student_gender', ['MALE', 'FEMALE'])->nullable(true);
    $table->text('student_address')->nullable(true);
    $table->tinyinteger('student_status')->default('1');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I've assumed that the `student_id` needs to be some kind of unique code in your application, so I've changed this to use the `string` function.  This will create a varchar type field, with the second parameter the length of the string.

I've also change the `tinyinteger` function parameters for `student_status`, it looks like you're trying to specify all the possible values, similar to your use of `enum`.  The `tinyinteger` type can not take a list of possible values, so you might want to either change this to a boolean (if the status is true or false), enum or foreign key to a related table if relevant.

If you are using Eloquent ORM in your application, there might not be the need for prefixing all your column names with `student`. If used correctly you should be able to simply use the name of the variable being stored, for example `student_name` would become `name`.